# Running same action multiple times in ModelBuilder model with increasing expression value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, expression, select-by-attribute, iteration

I have created this ModelBuilder model

[image]

in above expression value is 1 by default but I want to run expression value 2,3,4,5 and up to 50 (it may vary based my dataset).

I tried for while iteration but results not fruitful

Answer (score 3):

You dont mention what field type you have. But I have a string field called **kkod** with integers in it.

This model is working if I use the for loop output as input to a string variable, then use the string as input to an SQL expression variable:

[image]

Comment: great and it's working.

Comment: Nice, please accept my answer with the checkbox!

Answer (score 0):

The ModelBuilder does have a [for loop implementation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm) which sounds more appropriate than while in your use case.

This being said, iteration capabilities within ModelBuilder for ArcMap (which it seems you're using) are relatively limited. You can't batch custom models, and I think you are only allowed one iteration per model. To get around these, you can [export your model as a script](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008633) and do it programmatically.

Comment: i tried to use for loop but i can i connect **for loop to expression**